# Installing otbApplication.py to Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install otbApplication to use in my jupyter notebook on Windows. The program only has a direct path installation on linux and nothing I do seems to allow it to work.

I have tried creating a new environment leading to the py file, appending the sys path, and seeing if anaconda.org was able to provide me with a line to plug into the prompt to install it directly.

import otbApplication 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I wanted to be able to then use otb's band math functions but as it stands, it keeps telling me that the application is not defined